# Authenticating Mandrill Inbound Webhook Requests in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, mandrill, webhooks

I'm using Mandrill Inbound Webhooks to call a method in my WCF API. The request is coming through, I can successfully parse it, etc.

My problem lies in getting the value of the `X-Mandrill-Signature` header to match the signature that I'm generating (based on the process detailed here: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583257-Authenticating-webhook-requests).

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
List<string> keys = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params.AllKeys.ToList();
       keys.Sort();
       string url = "MyMandrillWebhookURL";
       string MandrillKey = "MyMandrillWebhookKey"
       foreach (var key in keys)
       {
           url += key;
           url += HttpContext.Current.Request.Params[key];
       }
       byte[] byteKey = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MandrillKey);
       byte[] byteValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
       HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(byteKey);
       byte[] hashValue = myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(byteValue);
       string generatedSignature = Convert.ToBase64String(hashValue);
```

And `generatedSignature` does not match the value for `X-Mandrill-Signature`

I know that the Mandrill docs indicate that the encoding needs to be done in binary and not hexadecimal (and I think my code does that, but correct me if I'm wrong), but, beyond that I can't make heads or tails of what my issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're retrieving the keys in your validation. You only need to use the request's POST variables alphabetically by key, not all the Request parameters. There is only one POST variable, mandrill_events that needs to be used in the signature generation.

```
string url = "MyMandrillWebhookURL";
string MandrillKey = "MyMandrillWebhookKey"
url += "mandrill_events";
url += mandrillEvents;
byte[] byteKey = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MandrillKey);
byte[] byteValue = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(url);
...
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. It seems that you are missing a closing double quotation, though, on the line `url += "mandrill_events;`.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you know of anywhere to test if my implementation works? Mandrill doesn't seem to have any example calculations to look at for verification.

Comment: Where does `mandrillEvents` come from? This is kind of key to the whole implementation.